# Symfony2 service arguments (as an expression language string)

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

As the Symfony2 [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language) describes, it's possible to inject an "expression language" string as a service argument, but it apperently doesn't work, even with a simple implementation :

```
services:
    my_service:
        class:     AAA\BBBBundle\ClassName
        arguments: ["@=container.hasParameter('param_name') ? parameter('param_name') : 'default_value'"]
```

i got:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'The service "my_service" has a dependency on a non-existent service "=container.hasparameter('some_param') ? parameter('some_param') : 'default_value'".' in /[...]/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php on line 59

have i missed something ?

Comment: Do you use Symfony 2.4?

Comment: What version of Symfony are you running?

Comment: i am currently under the 2.3.9 version of Symfony, indeed it's composer.json file does'nt contain yet the [Expression language bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/expression-language), so the problem come surely from here, thanks for the scent !

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear fully `app/cache` dir